# What is a merge?

Tags: discussion, merged-question

Recently I was looking at [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/5403/standard-pcb-trace-widths) question and one of the answer has this at the bottom of it:

> moderator note: This answer have arrived to this thread as a result of a merge.

What is a merge (I can guess but I am not sure I am guessing accurately)?

Is this something that is specific to Electronics.Stackexchange? Or is it universal to all SE sites?

Answer (score 4):

When questions are merged, answers and comments from the source question are moved to the destination question.  What remains from the source question is a so called merge stub (sometimes the stub gets manually deleted).

Merging isn't done often, because conditions for merging don't happen often.
Merging is available on all SE stacks.
Only moderators can perform a merge.